# Responsive CSS timeline with connecting lines

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a responsive timeline that behaves as (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KoGdqG):

1. For width higher than 600px is horizontal.
   The width of each section is responsive;
2. For width under than 600px becomes vertical;

So I have the following HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="mark"></span>
    <h3>Step 1</h3>
    <p>Some text that describes text 1</p>
  </li><li>
    <span class="mark"></span>
    <h3>Step 2</h3>
    <p>Some text that describes text 2</p>
  </li><li>
    <span class="mark"></span>
    <h3>Step 3</h3>
    <p>Some text that describes text 3</p>    
  </li><li>
    <span class="mark"></span>
    <h3>Step 4</h3>
    <p>Some text that describes text 4</p>
  </li>      
</ul>
```

And the following CSS:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
} 

body {
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  max-width: 1000px;  
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
  list-style: none;
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;  
}

li {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;  
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {  

  li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
  }

  li span {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }  

} 

@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {  

  ul {
    text-align: left;
  }

  li h3 {
    margin-left: 40px;
  }

  li p {
    margin-left: 40px;
  }  

} 

li span {
  background-color: white;  
  border: 2px solid green;                
  display: inline-block;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  border-radius: 12px;   
}

li h3 {
  text-align: left;
}

li p {
  text-align: left;
}
```

**PROBLEM**

The problem is how to create lines that connects each circle.

The lines become vertical with the vertical version of the timeline.

How can I do this?

Comment: I know this won't help you at all, but I tried to achieve the same exact result time ago, with no luck (except some js magic).
The problem is the dynamic distance between circles, which can't be easily calculated. With a fixed distance and  a bunch of media query it would be way easier, but not what you want I guess.
I starred your question hoping in some delightful solution

Comment: @CristianTraìna: Have a look at my answer, it's CSS only. The width and height of the list elements get's recalculated automatically depending on the screen width. That's why using borders with the li elements gives you correctly sized lines. Only thing left to do is to position the circles as desired.

Comment: Maybe this is ok for @MiguelMoura, but this isn't what I meant :) I meant to add an element between the two circles, and on resizing this element reduce its size in order to always stay between the circles.

Comment: I fiddled a bit with codepen, and I came up to this result:
https://codepen.io/crisz/pen/XExdbV
even though this works only horizontally and I didn't test it on all the browsers

Answer (score 1):

A solution (CSS only) is to connect each circle by adding borders to the list elements depending on the viewport width and repositioning the circle:

```
/* vertical connections */
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
  li {
    border-width: 0 0 0 1px !important; /* change visible border to left */
    margin-top: 0 !important; 
  }
  li span.mark {
    left: -12px; /* half circle height */
  }
}

/* for horizontal connections */
li {
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 0; /* show top border */
  margin-top: 15px;
}

li span.mark {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px; /* half circle height */
}
```

Your complete CSS (I've reorganized a bit) could look like this:

```
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  text-align: center
}

li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%
  }
  li span {
    margin: 0 auto
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
  li {
    border-width: 0 0 0 1px !important;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-top: 0 !important
  }
  li h3 {
    margin-left: 40px
  }
  li p {
    margin-left: 40px
  }
  li span.mark {
    left: -12px
  }
  ul {
    text-align: left
  }
}

li {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 0 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
  position: relative
}

li h3 {
  text-align: left
}

li p {
  text-align: left
}

li span {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid green;
  border-radius: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px
}

li span.mark {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px
}
```

**NOTE: Tested only in [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/geBPdy)!**

Answer (score 1):

Another way to make this work is using pseudo classes as well.
Add a div before the ul:

```
<div class="line"></div>
<ul>...</ul>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jzeqEM

Add these classes:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {  

  .line{
    width: 45%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 3px;
    background: black;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 33px;
   }  
}

@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {  

  li span::after{
    content: "";
    width: 3px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 140px;
    background: black;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 20px;
  }

  li:nth-child(4) span::after{
    content: "";   
    background: none;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a new element `.line` inside each `li`. The position of `.line` is calculated according to width (percentage) and margin (pixels):

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {  
  .line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 1px black;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    transform: translateX(calc(50% + 20px)) translateY(-18px);
  } 

  li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
  }

  li span {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }  

} 

@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {  
  .line {
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    border-left: solid 1px black;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    transform: translateX(-11px) translateY(calc(50% - 5px));
  } 

  li {
    display: table;
  }

  ul {
    text-align: left;
  }

  li h3 {
    margin-left: 40px;
  }

  li p {
    margin-left: 40px;
  }  

}
```

`li { display: table }` and `.line { display: table-cell } is a workaround to make the inner element aware of the height of the parent element. The height is calculated dynamically according to the text content, so we must use this or flexbox.

Here is a working snippet:

```css
* {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}



body {
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  max-width: 1000px;  
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 60%;
  list-style: none;
 list-style: none;
 list-style-type: none;  
}

li {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;  
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {  
  .line {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  border-top: solid 1px black;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(calc(50% + 20px)) translateY(-18px);
} 
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
  }
  
  li span {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }  
  
} 

@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {  
  li {
    display: table;
  }
  .line {
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    border-left: solid 1px black;
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    transform: translateX(-11px) translateY(calc(50% - 5px));
  } 
  ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  
  li h3 {
    margin-left: 40px;
  }

  li p {
    margin-left: 40px;
  }  
  
} 

li span {
  background-color: white;  
  border: 2px solid green;                
  display: inline-block;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  border-radius: 12px;   
}

li h3 {
  text-align: left;
}

li p {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="mark"></span>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <h3>Step 1</h3>
    <p>Some text that describes text 1</p>
  </li><li>
    <span class="mark"></span>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <h3>Step 2</h3>
    <p>Some text that describes text 2</p>
  </li><li>
    <span class="mark"></span>
    <div class="line"></div>
    <h3>Step 3</h3>
    <p>Some text that describes text 3</p>    
  </li><li>
    <span class="mark"></span>
    <h3>Step 4</h3>
    <p>Some text that describes text 4</p>
  </li>      
</ul>
```